# How to remove the "Powered by Google" logo in the Google Map Autocomplete dropdown list?

Tags: google-maps

Documentation suggests that if we were to use the Autocomplete with Google Maps, we can remove the "Powered by Google" logo at the bottom. Any idea how to go about doing?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Animesh Nandi**'s answer is a bit old.
Actually, to remove the '*powered by Google*' logo I had to use the following code:

```
.pac-container:after {
    /* Disclaimer: not needed to show 'powered by Google' if also a Google Map is shown */

    background-image: none !important;
    height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I would also add `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;`, otherwise it leaves a 2px white space after the last `.pac-item`. Maybe it was just for me, but this fixed it.

Comment: Is it even allowed to remove the logo(for commercial purposes)?

Comment: Any Idea about how I can do that in Android

Comment: @Animesh Nandi'-  Can you plz tell where to write this code in objective c? I need to remove 'powered by Google' in iOS

Comment: This solution is valid only if dealing with HTML/CSS (on mobile it depends on how your application is designed to work). In that case find the stylesheet file for your app and write the above code there.

Answer (score 18):

Check this out..

It is working in my app.

Place this in your stylesheet, and watch the magic.

`.pac-container:after{
    content:none !important;
}`

Comment: This is not valida anymore. Now the logo is set as `background-image` either in *.pac-container:after* and *.hdpi.pac-container:after*. See my answer beneath.

Comment: How can you see the markup that creates the autocomplete suggestions? I'd like to know how many elements are in the dropdown for accessibility.

Answer (score 7):

> Our Autocomplete services do not need to be used in conjunction with a map, but it does require a “powered by Google” logo to appear under the text field if a map isn’t shown.

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2012/09/google-places-autocomplete-now-includes.html

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, the "Powered by Google" image can be obscured by, clash with, or be inconsistent with the styles that you put on the autocomplete list. In these cases, it is desirable to replace the image with styled text.

The image itself is defined in an `:after` psuedo-element. All you have to is replace the `content` and `font-size` rules. Make sure that the text you use credits Google and be sure to set a font size because it's set to zero by default.

```
.pac-container:after {
  content: "Powered by Google";
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way to remove powered by google

```
.pac-container:after{display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 ways

First way

```
.pac-container:after {
    background-image: none !important;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Second way

```
.pac-container:after {
  content: none !important;
}
```

Both will remove the "Powered by Google" logo in the Google Maps autocomplete dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

if you using pods for iOS Google Autocomplete you can remove logo with remove source logo inside Pods -> GooglePlaces -> GooglePlaces.bundle -> Resources, there is logo named "powered-by-google.." remove that , clean project ,and rebuild (i don't know if this is allowed) but it is work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.pac-container:after{visibility: hidden!important;position: absolute; top: -9999px; 
left: -9999px;opacity: 0;width: 0; height: 0;}
```

---

**Disclaimer:** not needed to show 'powered by Google' if also a Google Map is shown – Thanks to [Kani's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462830/kani) comment

Comment: That's probably not how google mention it. Be carefully with such solution I think thats against the terms of use.